# How to simplify Apache Avro?

Tags: android, dependencies, avro

I am developing an Android project with Apache Avro, but it depends on two Jackson libs(core-asl.jar and mapper-asl.jar). Unfortunately, these two libs are too large for an Android application. I wonder if there is any way to simplify the Avro source code, or can I replace Jackson with org.json directly?

Comment: what do you mean by two large for an android application?

Comment: yes , you can Replace Jackson with org.json

Comment: @cgomezmendez generally smaller Android applications are preferable over bigger ones - they are faster to download for users. Also in my case I'm quite close to the limit on total number of methods.

Comment: @chandrakantsharma could you please post how to replace Jackson with org.json in Avro library?